# out of memory exception

Tags: java, android, exception, out-of-memory

I am new to android. I am doing image listing form sd-card.Following code give me error "Out of memory on a 614416-byte allocation."

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ll_sponsor_list_item,
                parent, false);

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imggrid_item_image);
        String imgurl = ImageName.get(position);

        AsyncImageLoaderv asyncImageLoaderv = new AsyncImageLoaderv();
        Bitmap cachedImage = asyncImageLoaderv.loadDrawable(imgurl,
                new AsyncImageLoaderv.ImageCallback() {
                    public void imageLoaded(Bitmap imageDrawable,
                            String imageUrl) {
                        img.setImageBitmap(imageDrawable);


                    }
                });
        img.setImageBitmap(cachedImage);
        cachedImage.recycle();
        return convertView;
    }
```

Class:

```
class AsyncImageLoaderv  {
    int width;
    int height;
    float aspectRatio;
    int newWidth;
    int newHeight;

    public Bitmap loadDrawable(final String imageUrl,
            final ImageCallback imageCallback) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                imageCallback.imageLoaded((Bitmap) message.obj, imageUrl);
            }
        };
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d("ur", imageUrl);
                    Bitmap drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUrl);
                    width = drawable.getWidth();
                    height = drawable.getWidth();
                    aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
                    newWidth = 98;
                    newHeight = (int) (98 / aspectRatio);
                    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(drawable, newWidth, newHeight,
                            true);
                    Message message = handler.obtainMessage(0, drawable);
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                    //this.sleep(1000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("thread stellent", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }.start();
        return null;
    }

    public interface ImageCallback {
        public void imageLoaded(Bitmap imageBitmap, String imageUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: check that images are heavy or not...This error shows that you are trying to load heavy image.

Comment: You are loading the image into memory, then scaling it. You should scale it using `inSampleSize`. There are many duplicate questions showing how to solve this. And android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in that question:

[Android - Outofmemory error by decodefile or decodeStream to convert the Uri selected to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973936/android-outofmemory-error-by-decodefile-or-decodestream-to-convert-the-uri-sel/13974240#13974240)

Bitmaps can not hold heavyweight pictures. Read this post, it is possible to reduce size of images.